# Javascript number interval search optimization

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization, numbers

As topic says i ran into optimization problem when it comes to a large amount of intervals

Variables: FirstPrice, LastPrice, Increment and the number that user writes

Task: Need to round number to one side or another in specific interval.

Example:
FirstPrice = 0.99, LastPrice = 9.99, Increment = 1 User number = 5.35

Workflow: 
I need to find interval in which one number exists, and what i could think of is to push numbers into array. So for this example array would be:
["0.99","1.99","2.99","3.99","4.99","5.99","6.99","7.99","8.99","9.99"].
Then i use for loop to find in which interval (in this case number = 5.35) number exists. In this case interval would be from 4.99 to 5.99. And then user number is updating to 4.99 or 5.99.

Problem: 
It works fine doing that with low amount of numbers. But it comes really hard to execute high ranges. E.g. if FirstPrice = 1 LastPrice = 1000000 and Increment = 1. Then my array gets thousands of values and it takes way too long to push every value into array and find the number. Array gets ~999999 values and then loop goes through all of them to find specific interval.

So i think my problem is clear. The optimization. I need a better way of doing this. I tried cutting price range to half and a half but then intervals are wrong. Tried working with the inserted number but the same problem occurred.

Comment: How about some math instead of this abomination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this simply:

```
lower = floor((q - s) / i) * i + s
upper = lower + i
```

where:

```
q = User number
s = FirstPrice
i = Increment
```

```js
function foo(q, s, i) {
  const lower = Math.floor((q - s) / i) * i + s;
  const upper = lower + i;

  return [lower, upper];
}

console.log(
  foo(5.35, 0.99, 1),
  foo(5.35, 0.99, 2),
  foo(5.35, 0.99, 3)
);
```

Comment: Oh god... I overthought so hard. This is way easier, thanks for your invested time, appreciate !